# How to Join Two Result sets to query on output came from Two query?

Tags: mysql, php

```
    $installments = "SELECT
       SUM( installments.t_fee ) AS paid_fee,
       sum(installments.exam_fee) as r_exam,
       sum(installments.lib_fee) as r_lib
    FROM  installments
    JOIN  student ON student.s_id = installments.s_id
    JOIN  program ON program.p_id = student.p_id
    WHERE  installments.paid =1
      AND  installments.curr_sem ='".$q['sem']."'
      AND  student.bat_id ='".$_GET['srch']."'
      AND  installments.s_id='".$q['s_id']."'
      AND  program.p_id='".$_GET['srch1']."'
      AND  student.DeleteStatus=0";

$installments = "SELECT  installments.curr_sem as semester
    FROM  installments
    JOIN  student ON student.s_id = installments.s_id
    JOIN  program ON program.p_id = student.p_id
    WHERE  installments.paid =1
      AND  installments.lib_fee!=0
      AND  student.DeleteStatus=0";
```

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Show what the output should look like.

Comment: UNION SQL construct should work. But sir, as Mark Sinkinson said, it's less secure.